# Determine all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $A_t$ is diagonalizable.

Tags: matrices, proof-verification, diagonalization

I have this matrix:

$$A_t=\begin{pmatrix}\phantom{-}2+t&\phantom{-}4&\phantom{-}2+t&\phantom{-}2+t\\\phantom{-}t-2&\phantom{-}0& -6+t&  -2-t\\-t+2&-4&-t+2&-2-t\\\phantom{-t+}0&\phantom{-}0&\phantom{-t+}0&\phantom{-t+}2t\end{pmatrix}$$

I must determine all $t\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $A_t$ is diagonalizable.

---

My solution:

PAt = (2t - X) det =

2+t-X  4  2+t

-2+t   -X  -6+t

2-t    -4  2-t-X

And through Gauss I achieve this form:

(2t-X) det =

4-X  0   4-X

0  -4-X -4-X

2-t  -4  2-t-X

=  (2t -X) (4-X) ((-4-X)(2-t-X)-(16+4X)-(-4-X)(2-t))

= (2t - X) (4-X) (-4-X) ((2-t-X) - (2-t) +4)

= (2t-X)(4-X)(-4-X)(2-t-X-2+t+4)

= (2t-X)(4-X)(-4-X)(4-X)

Kernel =

-2+t  4  2+t  2+t

0 -8 -8   -4-2t

0     0   0     2t-4

0     0   0     0

Kernel =

-2+t 4 2+t 2+t

```
 -8 -8  -8

        2t-4
```

Kernel =

-2+t  0 -2+t 0

```
 -8  -8  -8

        2t-4
```

So the basis is:

1
1
-1
0

for t != 2

for t = 2 the basis is:

1  0   0  0

0  1  -1  0

0  0   1 -1

So my question is, are my thoughts right ? Are they complete this way ? If not and it's not much which is left, could you complete it for me or at least give me a hint ? Or are there better ways to solve this, since our professor didn't really teach us how to solve this kind of tasks with parameters. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean diagonal, or diagonisable? I assume the latter. There is no number $t$ such that the matrix is diagonal.

Comment: I mean diagonisable, I'm sorry for my bad english (I translated some definitions wrong, I should have looked them up more), normally I would calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, set up a eigenspace etc and prove this way that it is diagonasible, but I don't really know how to do it for a matrix with parameters

Comment: Can somebody help me with this problem ?

Comment: People would be more likely to help you if your working out wasn't so unreadable. Try formatting your matrices uses TeX, so to write
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{array}\right]$$
you type
    \$\$\ left[\ begin {array}{cc}
a&b \ \
c&d
\ end {array}\ right]\$\$
with no spaces. The number of c's gives you the number of columns. So far, your working up to finding the eigenvalues looks fine, then I lose track of what you're trying to do. Remember when calculating the eigenspaces that you'll need to deal with the cases $t=2$ and $t=-2$ separately.

Comment: Ok thanks I will keep it in mind for next time and I solved that question on my own. So a mod can close this question or something.